# ng2-stomp-service and Spring Security

Tags: angular, spring-security, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket

I have an Angular 2 Application using ng2-stomp-service.  It works with Spring WebSocket without security.

But I cannot get Authentication credential to send over to Spring Security.  Here is the config in Spring Security:

```
   @EnableWebSecurity
   public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
       @Override
       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http
                .csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/demo-websocket/info").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/demo-websocket/**/websocket").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/info", "/health").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/info", "/health").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**", "/advisor").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        }
   }
```

Here is the Spring WebSocket Security Setup:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .simpTypeMatchers(CONNECT).permitAll()
                .simpTypeMatchers(UNSUBSCRIBE, DISCONNECT).permitAll()
                .simpMessageDestMatchers("/app/**").permitAll()
                .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/topic/**").permitAll()
                .anyMessage().authenticated()
        ;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        //disable CSRF for websockets for now...
        return true;
    }
}
```

Notice that "permitAll()" is being used such that it works without Authentication.  However, if ".simpMessageDestMatchers("/app/**").permitAll()" is changed to ".simpMessageDestMatchers("/app/**").authenticated()", it won't work.

Here is the Angular 2 setup:

```
this.stomp.configure({
            host: `http://${config.host}:${config.port}/demo-websocket`,
            debug: true,
            queue: {'init': false},
            headers: {
                login: 'user',
                passcode: 'password',
                authorization: `Basic ${this.calcBase64UserPassword()}`
            },
        });
```

Angular 2 code for connecting to Spring WebSocket:

```
 this.subject = new Subject<Greeting>();

            this.stomp.startConnect().then(() => {
                this.stomp.done('init');

                console.log('Connect established.');

                this.connected = true;

                this.subscription = this.stomp.subscribe('/topic/greetings', this.response.bind(this));
            });
```

Angular 2 code for sending a message via web socket:

```
send(messageText: string): void {
        if (this.connected) {
            const message = new DomainMessage(this.msgId, messageText);
            this.stomp.send('/app/hello', message, {
                login: 'user',
                passcode: 'password'
            });
        }
    }
```

Angular 2 code for calculating Basic Authentication Base 64 header:

```
private calcBase64UserPassword(username = config.username, password = config.password): string {
        const result = btoa(`${username}:${password}`);
        console.log (`${result}`);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Hi! did you find any solution? get stuck with the similar issue